# Why does git status for a particular repo return paths relative to the root instead of the current directory?

Tags: macos, git

When using git from a subdirectory inside a particular repo the paths of the files are returned relative to the root, like so

```
cd $REPO_ROOT/subdir
git status
...
#   modified ../subdir/file.txt
```

This behaviour is recent, it used to return `file.txt` instead, just as is does with my other git repos and it's messing up other features, `git blame file.txt` from the subdirectory returns every line as `Not Yet committed`, to get the actual output I need to use `../subdir/file.txt`. This is also messing up the vim git plugin so I'm quite annoyed.

I have already run `git gc` but the problem persists.

edit: adding git version and configs

```
git version 1.7.4.4

user.name=...
user.email=...
github.user=...
color.branch=auto
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch.current=yellow reverse
color.branch.local=yellow
color.branch.remote=green
color.diff.meta=yellow bold
color.diff.frag=magenta bold
color.diff.old=red
color.diff.new=green
color.status.added=green
color.status.changed=red
color.status.untracked=cyan

core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true

#remotes and branches 

status.relativepaths=true
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a configuration issue:

```
cd repo
git config status.relativePaths true
```

Or global:

```
git config --global status.relativePaths true
```

Further reading: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't quite fix it, from the subdirectory, with the flags set to off, the path gets displayed as `subdir/file.txt`, set to on: `../subdir/file.txt`. The behaviour I'm used to and which I see in other repos, is it should just return `file.txt`

Comment: @albemuth Please list `git --version` and output of `git config --list`.

Comment: `status.relativePaths` set to true should give the behavior you describe, which I believe is the default.  `../subdir/file.txt` would appear you ran a git status within a sibling directory of `subdir`

Comment: @roispov, please see edit. @steve, this is true for other repos, however that's what I'm seeing while on `subdir`on this repo. Now that you mention that though, I wonder if there's some permission problem or filesystem corruption which makes git not know the path of the file is the same as the one it is in.

Comment: @albemuth I suggest re-cloning the repo and see if problem persists. Maybe some data got corrupted somehow.

Comment: I have the same situation. Probably the case is that I've moved subdir on dir lower. That is `/subdir1/subdir2` in to `/subdir2`.