# How can I get paths relative to the current directory from git status?

Tags: git, path, relative-path, git-status

I wish to use the output from <kbd>git status</kbd> in a script but, because the output is always giving repo-relative file paths, other commands can't find their args.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795105/why-does-git-status-for-a-particular-repo-return-paths-relative-to-the-root-inst) mentioned the relativePaths option but it has no effect on output when given as a command option:

<kbd>git -c status.relativePaths=true status --short</kbd>

If I've got a changed file at `C:\projects\myproject\config\module\feature.src`, and I'm sitting at a command prompt in `C:\projects\myproject\web\somepage` , then I'd need a path like either of these:

- `..\..\config\module\feature.src`
- `C:\projects\myproject\config\module\feature.src`

...to be able to hand that off to other tools that I want to invoke on newly-changed files. Instead, with the repo based in `myproject\`, every combination of options I've tried has yielded only

- `config\module\feature.src`

So how can I get actual relative paths, or even absolute paths? Am I missing something basic?

I'm using git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2 on Windows 7 with the repo files in an external folder. I can provide a List Of Things I've Tried That Didn't Work. I can have my script query and <kbd>cd</kbd> to the repo root before running other commands, or do it myself first, but those are just workarounds.

Comment: You want relativepaths=false not true

Comment: @Andrew `git -c status.relativePaths=false status` still gives paths relative to the repository root. According to all the documentation this is _supposed_ to work. Maybe there's a Windows-specific bug?

Comment: Unsure.  Linux 2.3.0 works as advertised.  I don't use windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `git config status.relativePaths true`. Read more in the `configuration` section [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status).

Comment: I don't know what's going on with my work project but I set up a folder structure and new repository as in the example paths above, and status.relativePaths has the expected effects when I use it there.Accepting this answer since it is evidently accurate as long as no other factors are introducing insanity. (For now I'm going to cast a suspicious eye on msysgit and the fairly old version of the Windows build!)